# Storing Statistics Data in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

We want to analyze the usage of our application and therefor want to store the usage data in an influxdb. We want to store data like Session Start Time, Browser, Browser Version, OS, Language, Available Languages, etc.

We then want to know e.g. what the top 5 Browsers are (with percent of sessions or percent of users), or which the most often used OS is.

How would I store this data in influxdb in order to be able to get such reports as described above or are there better databases to store such data.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are not dealing with timeseries data. Your data is structured as per my evaluation. You should use one of the relational databases like MySQL or PostgreSQL.

You can go ahead with InfluxDB if you are dealing with regular/irregular time series data.

Comment: Depending on how you define tineseries, the data is a timeseries. It is points in time in which a specific browser has accessed the application. But you might be right, that SQL fits better here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use InfluxDB for this. You'd want to store this information as events in the database.

So when a user browses to your application, that would be an event and you'd store something like:

```
user_events,browser="Chrome",country="UK",os="Linux",language="en_GB",url="/home" some_field=1 TIMESTAMP
```

This is Line Protocol:

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/write_protocols/line_protocol_tutorial/